# distinctUntilChanged not working (e.g. different list size is not considered different)

Tags: android, rx-java2

My observable looks like following:

```
obs
    .doOnNext { logger("Items changed (${it.size})") }
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .doOnNext { logger("Items changed (${it.size})- EMIITTED") }
```

Log looks like following:

```
Items changed (7)
Items changed (7)- EMIITTED
Items changed (8)
// => missing EMIITTED message although it.size has changed => WHY?
```

Using the default comparator with a list of comparable items seems to fail here. Why? If the observables emitted list item size changed, the data is different, so `distinctUntilChanged` should not filter out the new list. But it seems like this happens here. Why?

Do I really need to provide my own comparator for `distinctUntilChanged` if I emit a list of items that compares the list size and the items one by one?

**Edit**

My `obs` basically looks like following:

```
obs = Observable.combineLatest(
    RxDBDataManager.appsManager.observeList(),
    RxDBDataManager.widgetsManager.observeList(),
    RxDBDataManager.shortcutsManager.observeList(),
    RxDBDataManager.customItemsManager.observeList(),
    RxDBDataManager.foldersManager.observeList(),
    Function5<List<IDBApp>, List<IDBWidget>, List<IDBShortcut>, List<IDBCustomItem>, List<IDBFolder>, List<IFolderOrSidebarItem>> { t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 ->
        val list = ArrayList<IFolderOrSidebarItem>()
        list.addAll(t1)
        list.addAll(t2)
        list.addAll(t3)
        list.addAll(t4)
        list.addAll(t5)
        list
    }
    .flatMapSingle {
        Observable.fromIterable(it)
                .filter { it.parentType == parentType && it.parentId == parentId }
                .cast(T::class.java)
                .toList()
    }
    .flatMapSingle {
        Observable.fromIterable(it)
                .sorted(comparator)
                .toList()
    }
```

Additionally I apply some sorting and filtering on this data with

Comment: Do you by any chance use a mutable list so you are sending basically the same list instance over and over?

Comment: I added my base observable, as you can see I'm using mutable items and a mutable list, but I create new lists every time something changes

Comment: I suggest you do add a custom [bi-predicate](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#distinctUntilChanged-io.reactivex.functions.BiPredicate-) so that you can place a breakpoint in the implementation and inspect the two list instances in the debugger.

Comment: That's it, seems like I somewhere do edit the list. Must investigate this a little further

Comment: `toList` always gives you a fresh list. You could `map` the output of `toList` via `Collections::unmodifyableList()` and it will crash where the modification is attempted.

Comment: I found out that I somewhere adjust the old list, because the lists are different but contain the same content... Must find out where this happens, then everything should work as expected

Comment: Additionally, the `Collections::unmodifyableList()` hint was worth gold, could find my problem immediately with this "trick", so thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Based on the exchange in the comments:*

RxJava users are encouraged to use immutable data types in its flows which prevents concurrency issues such as modifying the same object at different stages from different threads resulting in broken operator behavior and seemingly impossible business logic failures.

In this case, `distinctUntilChanged` didn't work as expected because mutable items were changed in a way that two subsequent `onNext` signals basically had the same content and the operator filtered them out as being non-distinct.

A way to detect if the items involved are in fact the same unintentionally is to use the bi-predicate version of the operator and then placing a breakpoint in the custom lambda. This lets one inspect the previous and current values and see if they are truly equal even if they shouldn't be:

```
source.distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) -> {
    // breakpoint the next line
    return prev.equals(curr);
});
```

As in this case, broken behavior was due to a mutable item changed somewhere and thus evaluating as the same as the current/previous. With `List`s, it is often not practical to breakpoint all mutation methods (such as `add`, `addAll`, `set`, `remove` etc.) but one can turn a mutable list into an immutable one and send it along the sequence. The built-in way is to convert it via the `Collections::unmodifiableList`:

```
  source
  .toList()
  .map(Collections::unmodifiableList)
  ;
```

This will crash whenever a mutation is attempted on the now unmodifiable list instance, pointing to the logic that should be investigated further.